# No definition for ClickEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my code below, I am trying to simulate the Click event for my button `Browse`.

```
private void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Browse.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'ClickEvent'

How can I raise the click event?

**It appears there are some who are questioning the purpose of this code.  I got it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/733974/1477388 and am simply trying to make it work.**

Comment: @spender No, it appears that is not an option either.

Comment: I don't believe Spender's comment was meant as an answer I think they are trying to ask you what is `ButtonBase.Click` ??

Comment: `HighCore` that's a strictly opinionated comment perhaps his requirements are for he / she to use WinForms

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't know if I can answer that, as per my edit, I have found this code at the link posted above and I am trying to make it work.

Comment: @HighCore has it. What's Winforms got to do with it? This should be ButtonBase in a WPF namespace.

Comment: @spender the error clearly states `'System.Windows.[[Forms]].ButtonBase' does not contain a definition for 'ClickEvent'

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I agree. You've found the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're working with a WPF application

```
this.Browse.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

(routed events are part of WPF, not winforms), however you've referenced the wrong namespace

> '**System.Windows.Forms**.ButtonBase' does not contain a definition for 'ClickEvent'

Go to the top of your class and remove the following

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and replace it with

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
```

Blam.

Comment: That seems to fix it; however, now I can't use `OpenFileDialog`

Comment: @user1477388 Use `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`. Forget winforms, it's a really old technology no one cares about anymore.

Comment: @HighCore: Your original version is more correct.  Winforms compared to wpf is crap.

Comment: Okay, okay, please don't kill my inbox with a winforms/wpf debate.  Besides, WPF wins.  So there's no point.

Comment: @Will: Obviously WPF is better, just pointed out that WinForms is still quite relevant in some regards.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clicks should not fire on `MouseDown`.
2. [Put the `TextBlock` in a `Button`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831110/546730) or use a `Hyperlink`.
3. That code looks fine otherwise, however you have a `using` for the wrong namespace (WinForms) instead of WPF. You want: `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives`

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the code that you want to be called at the Click event into a method
2. Call this method at the Click event
3. Call this method at the MouseDown event

Comment: Actually, this solves the problem since I simply called Button_Click directly from my XAML code instead of calling another method to call it from the .cs code.  I am still wondering why it won't find that event though.

Comment: I did that for the longest time, too. Unfortunately, you end up using null parameters etc. which is always ugly. Use a dedicated method that only takes parameters that are actually used. Easier on the eye.