# How to implement a timer which calls a button's event in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

As I understand, the DispatcherTimer's Tick event needs to be called with EventArgs, whereas the same event calls the action of some buttons, which need to be called with RoutedEventArgs. Obviously, I cannot call the buttons' events directly. My question is: is there any way to implement this, by all means?

```
private void song_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playing == true)
        {
            lbl_curent_time.Text = audio_device.audioFileReader.CurrentTime.ToString();

            if (music_state_progress.Value < music_state_progress.Maximum)
            {
                music_state_progress.Value = music_state_progress.Value + 1;
                taskbar.SetProgressValue(Convert.ToInt32(music_state_progress.Value), Convert.ToInt32(music_state_progress.Maximum));
            }

            if (lbl_curent_time.Text == audio_device.audioFileReader.TotalTime.ToString())
                if (music_list.SelectedIndex < music_list.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    btn_next_Click(sender, e);
                    music_list_DoubleClick(sender, e);
                }
                else if (repeat_checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    music_list.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    music_list_DoubleClick(sender, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    btn_stop_Click(sender, e);
                    lbl_curent_time.Text = "00:00:00.0000000";
                    lbl_max_time.Text = "00:00:00.0000000";
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `EventArgs` in button click handler?

Comment: Nope, RoutedEventArgs, as it is required by WPF.

Comment: I would then suggest to extract out the code to some common place and call that method from button click handler and from your tick handler. You don't have to worry about it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
btn_stop_Click(sender, e);
```

with:

```
btn_stop.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer =
  new ButtonAutomationPeer( someButton );
IInvokeProvider invokeProv =
  peer.GetPattern( PatternInterface.Invoke )
  as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728432/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button-in-wpf)