# How to fire all event programatically in C#/XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, button, windows-phone-8.1

I have a button  in Windows Phone 8.1.

Button x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="button1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,141,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button1_Click" PointerMoved="button1_PointerMoved" KeyDown="button1_KeyDown"/

How to fire all event of the button automatically? (Click, PointerMoved, KeyDown)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728432/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of the delegates from `event`

```
var handler = myButton.Click;
var allDelegates= e.GetInvocationList();
```

And call each one in the for loop

```
foreach (var delegate in allDelegates) 
{
   delegate();
}
```