# How do I simulate a button click programmatically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WinForms it was easy to trigger a button click in code, because the [System.Windows.Forms.Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a public method called [PerformClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can call directly.

However, in WPF you end up using the [System.Windows.Controls.Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead, in which I'm not readily seeing any equivalent method. There is a method called OnClick but it's protected and I'm not sure it would actually trigger a click anyway; it seems to be fired in tandem with the click event.

```
var button = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
// how would I trigger the click event here, programmatically?
```

Comment: Can you not reference the forms assembly and trigger the event like you did before?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/733974/4699710

Comment: @ilian000 - that's perfect. Somehow I missed that one in my initial Google searches. If a mod wants to close this question as a duplicate that's fine by me; this was the answer I was looking for.