# ArgumentException constructing RoutedEventArgs with MouseDownEvent

Tags: wpf, click, mouseevent, richedit-control

I am trying to simulate a mouse click on a [`RichEditControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfRichEditRichEditControltopic). The underlying problem I am trying to solve is to set `Focus` on this control if the user takes another action without ever having clicked the `RichEditControl` first. Seems that if you bring up a form and never click the `RichEditControl`, something isn't initialized and the cursor won't appear.

I have read several helpful [blogs](https://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/wpf-simulate-mouse-click-in-code-behind/) and [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728432/how-to-programmatically-click-a-button-in-wpf) on the matter, and they all seem to point me to doing something of the form

```
RichEdit.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs( <something> );
```

I've written these four lines of code:

```
1. RichEdit.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
2. RichEdit.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs(RichEditControl.MouseDoubleClickEvent));
3. RichEdit.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs(RichEditControl.MouseDownEvent));
4. RichEdit.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs(RichEditControl.MouseUpEvent));
```

(1) does nothing. This makes sense because `ClickEvent` belongs to `Button`, not `RichEditControl`. (2) does nothing. It's a double-click. I want a click.

(3) and (4) are what's tripping me up. I'm getting an `ArgumentException`

> Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'.

This makes no sense to me. `MouseDownEvent` is of type `RoutedEvent`. the constructor to `RoutedEventArgs` is expecting a `RoutedEvent` as an argument. `RaiseEvent()` is expecting an argument of type `RoutedEventArgs`. Everything compiles fine without warnings. Looking at the stack trace, the exception occurs deeper, at `System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType`.

While I have serious doubts this will solve my underlying problem, I still want to try to force-feed a mouse click to the `RichEditControl` to see if this solves my problem. So my question is, why is `MouseDoubleClickEvent` causing an `ArgumentException` when, from what I can tell, I'm passing in correct types?

Comment: Have you tried using a MouseButtonEventArgs instead? RichEdit.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, DateTime.Now, MouseButton.Left));

Comment: I'm testing a tentative solution that involves [`FocusKeyCodeTextBox`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfRichEditRichEditControl_FocusKeyCodeTextBoxtopic) that looks like it will solve my underlying problem. Either way, I will circle back around and try your approach.